# WebSphere 7- Unable to debug, able to run

Tags: websphere

I've Web Sphere Application Server 7 under 64bit Windows machine.
I'm able to run it but not to debug: I use websphere jdk 7 for server coming from installation. It seems jdwp not to be attached....

**debug** configurations are

-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=7777

and error is about initialization:

JVMJ9TI001E unable to open jdwp agent library (can not find the specified module.
JVMJ9VM015W Initialization error for library j9jvmti24 (-3): 

JVMJ9VM009E J9VMDll Could not create the Java virtual machine.

Comment: WAS 7 does not support JDK 7. I am assuming you are making a typo!

Comment: ops, I meant WAS 7 JDK which is a 1.6 JDK :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this problem: associated service for the profile involved must be set on 'manual' mode...

so it works!

Comment: Would be nice if you provided us with more details on this - like where to set it.